# Boost chose between SSL ans TLS

Tags: sockets, ssl, boost, boost-asio

I use boost socket with SSL by using the following source code:

```
ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::sslv23);
ctx.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_peer);
ctx.load_verify_file("ca.pem");
```

I would like to know if ssl::context::sslv23 also activates TLS ?

If I want to force TLS connection (no SSL connection), Does it work:

```
ctx.set_options( boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2 | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3 );
```

Same question with SSL connection only:

```
ctx.set_options( boost::asio::ssl::context::no_tlsv1 );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to refer OpenSSL documentation, since asio::ssl::context is a thin wrapper for SSL_CTX. Thus ssl::context constructor calls [SSL_CTX_new()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_new.html) function with an appropriate method. As well as the ssl::context::set_options() function calls [SSL_CTX_set_options()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html) function.

In particular, for ssl::context::sslv23 method it would be:

> SSLv23_method(void), SSLv23_server_method(void),
>   SSLv23_client_method(void) A TLS/SSL connection established with these
>   methods may understand the SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2
>   protocols.
>
> If the cipher list does not contain any SSLv2 ciphersuites (the
>   default cipher list does not) or extensions are required (for example
>   server name) a client will send out TLSv1 client hello messages
>   including extensions and will indicate that it also understands
>   TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2 and permits a fallback to SSLv3. A server will
>   support SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 protocols. This is the best
>   choice when compatibility is a concern.
>
> If any SSLv2 ciphersuites are included in the cipher list and no
>   extensions are required then SSLv2 compatible client hellos will be
>   used by clients and SSLv2 will be accepted by servers. This is not
>   recommended due to the insecurity of SSLv2 and the limited nature of
>   the SSLv2 client hello prohibiting the use of extensions.
>
> The list of protocols available can later be limited using the
>   SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3, SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1, SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1
>   and SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2 options of the SSL_CTX_set_options() or
>   SSL_set_options() functions. Using these options it is possible to
>   choose e.g. SSLv23_server_method() and be able to negotiate with all
>   possible clients, but to only allow newer protocols like TLSv1,
>   TLSv1.1 or TLS v1.2.
>
> Applications which never want to support SSLv2 (even is the cipher
>   string is configured to use SSLv2 ciphersuites) can set
>   SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2.